# Prove that the minimum weight edge, e, which connects a vertex from V1 to V2 must be a part of a minimum spanning tree of G.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph with vertices in the set V partitioned into two sets V1 and V2. Prove that
the minimum weight edge, e, which connects a vertex from V1 to V2 must be a part of a
minimum spanning tree of G.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that if $T$ is a spanning tree and $e$ is an edge not in $T$ then $T\cup e$ has a unique cycle (one that uses $e$, of course).